# Finding number of elements $(x,y)$ such that $y^2=x^3+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p,$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $p\equiv 2(\mod 3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory

I have been trying to solve this problem for different values of $p.$ For instance, for $p=5,$
$$(x,y)=(0,1),(0,4),(2,2),(2,3),(4,0)$$ satisfies the problem. So we can say tha the given problem has $5$ solutions for $p=5.$

My problem is what can be said about all other primes. Is there any general method to calculate such problem. Intuitively, it seems that for all prime $p$ satisfying the given condition, $(x,y)$ must have at least $2$ solutions and at most $2p$ solutions. But I am unable to prove it.

Comment: By the Hasse theorem – https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves – there are $p+2u_p\sqrt{p}$ solutions (not counting the “point at infinity”), where $-1\leq u_p \leq 1$.

Comment: How is this related to the given problem?

Comment: $y^2=x^3+1$ is an elliptic curve on $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p > 3$. If $p-2$ is divisible by $3$ then by quadratic reciprocity its discriminant isn't a square (though I don't know how much it helps). By a Deuring (CM case -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638807/complex-multiplication-of-y2-x3b ) theorem, we know that this implies some sort of equidistribution for these numbers of points. But I realized there was an exact solution: simply show that $x \in \mathbb{F}_p  \longmapsto x^3 \in \mathbb{F}_p$ is injective (hence bijective), and the count of solutions follows easily.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So the given problem should have at least $2$ and at most $2p$ solutions. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes – but there’s an exact solution actually.

Comment: Wait...are we talking $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or $\mathbb{F}_p$? Those are two quite different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $3\ \nmid \ p-1$ then $f(z)=z^3$ is bijective $\Bbb{F}_p\to \Bbb{F}_p$ (use $z^p = z$ to check that its inverse is $z\to z^{(2p-1)/3}$)  thus
$$E(\Bbb{F}_p) = O \cup \{ (f^{-1}(y^2-1),y),y\in \Bbb{F}_p\}$$
$O$ is the point $(\infty,\infty)$ that we add to make it a group (the discriminant is $-27$)